# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'init_scope' during train.py

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I have a problem during the train.py execution.

This is the command line :

```
python train.py --logtosderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_inception_v2_coco.config
```

This is the result :

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/vivien/.conda/envs/tensorflow_cpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py:125: main (from __main__) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use object_detection/model_main.py.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/vivien/analyse_video/TensorFlow/models/research/object_detection/legacy/trainer.py:266: create_global_step (from tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops.variables) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please switch to tf.train.create_global_step
WARNING:tensorflow:num_readers has been reduced to 1 to match input file shards.
INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 184, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/home/vivien/.conda/envs/tensorflow_cpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 125, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/home/vivien/.conda/envs/tensorflow_cpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 250, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "train.py", line 180, in main
    graph_hook_fn=graph_rewriter_fn)
  File "/home/vivien/analyse_video/TensorFlow/models/research/object_detection/legacy/trainer.py", line 393, in train
    train_config.load_all_detection_checkpoint_vars))
  File "/home/vivien/analyse_video/TensorFlow/models/research/object_detection/meta_architectures/ssd_meta_arch.py", line 1321, in restore_map
    for variable in variables_helper.get_global_variables_safely():
  File "/home/vivien/analyse_video/TensorFlow/models/research/object_detection/utils/variables_helper.py", line 174, in get_global_variables_safely
    with tf.init_scope():
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'init_scope'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the commit d530ac5 for the tensorflow/models github repo solved the issue for me.
Refer to this [Tensorflow issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/issues/324#issuecomment-513847409).